# When heating, furnace blower turns on only in "ON" mode, not in "AUTO" mode

Tags: blower

I have a York unit that is having problems with the furnace. The furnace turns on but the blower doesn't turn on when set to "AUTO" mode, only when in "ON" mode. "AUTO" works fine when cooling. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've edited your post to not be yelling, and removing your contact info (that isn't how we work here). Please take our tour to see how to better participate.

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram of your furnace?